# Bash. Извлечение подстроки

Tags: строки, bash, shell

В переменной лежит значение типа `"текст1:текст2"`.

Как взять часть этой строки после двоеточия?

Comment: @avp Нет, не одно. У товарища существует такой вариант записи `2015-02-19  13:06:10.299`

@Roman Novoselov, вы бы в Вашем [предыдущем вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/401089/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-bash-shell) указали все задачи

Comment: Теперь все должно работать.

Answer (score 10):

Можно взять части строк в bash, не используя внешних комманд:

```
$ v="текст1:текст2"
$ echo ${v%:*} # убрать всё после последнего двоеточия
текст1
$ echo ${v#*:} # убрать всё до первого двоеточия
текст2
```

Comment: Спасибо оргомное

Answer (score 6):

Если двоеточие одно и текст в переменной v

```
tail=`echo $v | cut -d: -f 2`
```

*update*

Почитал немного man cut. Если двоеточие  не одно (с одним, впрочем, тоже работает), то надо так

```
tail=`echo $v | cut -d: -f 2-`
```

(а добавили-то всего один символ...)