# Разбить строку в массив и по элементно

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Есть строка `/hdd/3Tb/ARHIVE/2004/АПРЕЛЬ/Date_mgn4/Account/account.dbf`
нужно средствами bash
1 вытащить следующие: mgn4;Account;Date_mgn4;account.dbf из всего этого знаю что account.dbf можно вытащить basename(), а как остальное получить?
2 загнать эту строку в массив так чтоб a(0)=/hdd,a(1)=/3Tb и т.п

Comment: Ну с массивом просто: `str="/hdd/3Tb/ARHIVE/2004/АПРЕЛЬ/Date_mgn4/Account/account.dbf"; IFS="/"; a=( $str );` только потом IFS верните, если он вам нужен будет. И нумерацию элементов посмотрите, нулевой пустым будет т.к. там косая. А вот как выполнять остальное сказать невозможно так как нет четких критериев как получить именно эти элменты, по номеру или может по содержимому или еще как. А так же как выделять mgn4 по подчеркиванию или последние 3 буквы

Comment: [`IFS=/`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9479814/4279) удобно здесь использовать. [`"${a[6]#*_}"`](http://ideone.com/3CvkdT) вернёт `mgn4`. См. [Shell script: Как взять часть строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/401184/23044)

Answer (score 1):

**вариант 1:** поместить элементы в массив:

```
p=/hdd/3Tb/ARHIVE/2004/АПРЕЛЬ/Date_mgn4/Account/account.dbf
IFS=/ read -a a <<< $p
echo ${a[7]} # выведет строку "Account"
echo ${a[6]} # выведет строку "Date_mgn4"
```

**вариант 2:** воспользоваться программами *dirname* и *basename*:

```
p=/hdd/3Tb/ARHIVE/2004/АПРЕЛЬ/Date_mgn4/Account/account.dbf
echo $(basename $(dirname "$p")) # выведет строку "Account"
echo $(basename $(dirname $(dirname "$p"))) # выведет строку "Date_mgn4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Для нарезки по разделителю есть утилита `cut`

Для матчинга по части известной строки - `grep`

Для сложных действий по преобразованию строки в строку есть `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Проблему вложенности пути решал при помощи **find** (GNU findutils), опробовал на кешсервере 30тб.

```
~# find /library -type d -printf "%d %p\n" \
| sort -rn \
| awk "/2\s/{printn $2}"
```

Однострочник создаст список каталогов отсортированный по вложенности - опция *%d*.

И в зависимости от задачи, меняйте значение у *awk "/глубина\s/ {print $2}"*

В вашем случае:

```
ARRAY_PATH=( $(find /hdd -type d -printf "%d %p\n" | sort -nr | awk '{print $2}') )
```

Самый глубокий путь:

```
echo ${ARRAY_PATH[1]}
```

Количество путей:

echo ${#ARRAY_PATH}